# How to import CA200Srvr.dll on visual studio 2015 update3 by C#

Tags: c#

I use language C# to control Minlota color analyzer CA210.
But I don't know how to import CA200Srvr.dll on visual studio 2015 update3.
It can't add reference on visual studio 2015 update3 either.

Somebody can help to show me how to import CA200Srvr.dll by C#.

Comment: Check http://www.konicaminolta.com.cn/instruments/download/software/pdf/ca-sdk_guide_en.pdf

Comment: hi Jim,
Thanks for your information. 
It seems  visual studio 2015 update3 issue.
Due to I can add CA200Srvr.dll to reference on  visual studio 2015 update2.